# Mustache render on the server (rails) and on the client (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mustache

Is there any documentation on Mustache best practices when using on the server (with rails) and on the client (with javascript)?

```
# hello_world.mustache
Hello {{planet}}

# some other file
<%
hello_world_template = File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/hello_world.mustache")
%>

<script id="hello_world_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <%= hello_world_template %>
</script>

<script>
    // $.mustache = using mustache.js and a jquery mustache wrapper 
    // search on "Shameless port of a shameless port"
    document.write($.mustache($("#hello_world_template").html(), { "planet" : "World!" }));
</script>

<%= Mustache.render(hello_world_template, :planet => "World!") %>
```

The above isn't scalable. I'd prefer not to make my own engine for this.

Is there a more complete templating engine that allows reuse of templates on the server and on the client?

Additionally, one that accounts for nested templates on the server and the client?

Comment: I have found that the best way to accomplish this is by using Node.js with Express webserver, RequireJS, Backbone.js, and any template engine. Works beautifully on the client or the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Poirot](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot) available: Mustache + Rails 3.

Comment: I'll check this out, thanks. I've also seen something called Isotope. reading through that now. http://devign.me/isotope-hybrid-ruby-on-rails-template-engine-for-client-side-and-server-side/

Answer (score 2):

not familiar with the ruby on rails syntax but here is my take:

a) Why do you want to generate the markup on the server side at all (if at all that is an option) always send in json data to the client and let js mustache engine deal with it

b) if you still want to keep your server side rendering engine, then what you can do is keep all your mustache templates in a folder write a script that you execute during your build (or equivalent in ruby on rails) that combines all the templates into a nicely scoped JS file with the right naming conventions.

Something as follows:

```
var MUSTACHE_TEMPLATES= MUSTACHE_TEMPLATES || (function(){
var template1= "<big ass template>";
var template2="<small template>";

return
{
template1: template1,
template2: template2
}
}());
```

What do you think of that approach? Now you have your templates living in a single location and you also get the advantages of the js file being cached

Comment: I'd rather use the <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> approach as it's more explicit and easier for non-Javascript gurus to grasp.

Comment: And I want to render on both the server and the client because I want full html pages for SEO sake, and people are simply used to getting a full webpage load. Basically, this isn't an application, it's a website enhanced with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The [stache](https://github.com/agoragames/stache) gem seams to be what you need. Mustache or handlebars + Rails 3 or Rails 4