# Javascript Templating vs Server Templating

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, extjs, server-side, template-engine

Recently i was about to start a pet project with a fellow friend, We got on a debate on how to build the website, Whether to let the server take care of the template and data manipulation or use some JavaScript UI library like ExtJS/Jquery UI to render the widgets dynamically and use the server as a service that allows data flow.

What is better? JavaScript to handle the UI/Events and everything frontend with the backend only being data services OR the conventional MVC using backend frameworks (preferably ruby)?

And what are the correct/(easy to use) frameworks to use for the 2 scenarios. Also in which use-case is each preferred over the other.

Answer (score 3):

Neither is better. Each has it's own uses.

For the base site interface, you should always have the server create the initial structure of the site. This, therefore, needs server-side templating. This is also for those "if JS were off" or "JS isn't supported". At least a basic form of the site shows up. Don't be like Facebook before, where turning off JS leaves you with a blank page because it was too reliant on JS.

For widgets, dynamic tasks and operations that fetch data via AJAX, client-side templating should be done. AJAX is all about asynchronicity and speed, and returning formatted mark-up from the server is just too bulky. This is where you use JSON, where you cache your template strings, and use client-side templating.

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be to use Mustache, which can be rendered on both the server-side and client-side. See this blog post for how to share them between the two:

http://blog.railsware.com/2012/04/12/shared-mustache-templates-for-rails-3/

Comment: Also there is Poirot: https://github.com/olivernn/poirot, there is a question discussing Mustache/Rails over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045656/mustache-render-on-the-server-rails-and-on-the-client-javascript